# How do I create an image filter in Symfony2 AvalancheImagineBundle?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2 and I just installed the [AvalancheImagineBundle](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle) successfully. I created my own thumbnail filter as described in the README, and I created a 2nd filter called "profile" which (for the moment just to make sure it works) does the same thing as the thumbnail.

```
// app/config/config.yml
# Avalanche Imagine Configuration
avalanche_imagine:
    web_root:     %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    cache_prefix: images/cache
    driver:       gd
    filters:
        my_thumb:
            type:    thumbnail
            options: { size: [100, 100], mode: outbound }
        profile:
            type:    thumbnail         <-- HOW DO I DEFINE OTHER TYPES?
            options: { size: [200, 200], mode: outbound }
```

However, I don't want profile to be a thumbnail. **My Question:** How do I define new "types" of filters?

**Edit:** I've seen the [example](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle/blob/master/Imagine/Filter/Loader/ThumbnailFilterLoader.php) that the README gives, but I can't understand how to write my own filter. I want to write a simple filter that takes a "width" parameter and scales the image down to have that width.

**Update:** I've been fiddling with these image filters for a while now, and I am still just as lost as before.... Could someone provide me with a hint in the right direction? I'm working on an open source project if it encourages anyone :)

Answer (score 2):

It's funny to reply to your question here as I'm the creator and maintainer of Imagine :)

Basically, to add a filter to a bundle is a several step process

- Create filter loader - a class that implements Avalanche\Bundle\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Filter\Loader\LoaderInterface
- Register it in the Symfony DIC as a service and properly tag it
  Here is how the default thumbnail filter loader is tagged

  You can find it in the source of the bundle here - https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/imagine.xml#L100
- Finally, specify your filter in the yaml, use whatever value you specified in the "filter" attribute of your loader tag:

  ```
  avalanche_imagine:
      filters:
          my_thumb:
              type:    <your filter name>
              options: { #your options# }
  ```

Let me know if you run into any issues, additionally, feel free to create issues in the github repository of the bundle.

Cheers!

Comment: if it's possible could you paste the yml format for the DIC container here. I find it very hard to follow and convert from xml to yml even from the existing example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the "Load your Custom Filters" chapter in the [README](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle)? It tells you how to configure your filter.

For an example implementation look at the [ThumbnailFilterLoader](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle/blob/master/Imagine/Filter/Loader/ThumbnailFilterLoader.php) class.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. It just seems like some wrapper for the `Thumbnail` class that's built in. It doesn't demonstrate to me how to write a non-thumbnail one. All I want is to create a filter that accepts one parameter (width) and scales down the photo to the requested width.